# How to change ionic app structure. cli 3 same cli2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to change structure of an app. How to set `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`? How to find app.js?

Cli 3:

[image: Cli 3]

Cli 2:

[image: Cli 2]

Comment: are you using ionic 1 or ionic 2+ ?

Comment: I use Ionic 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CLi 3 image, you have created an Ionic 3 project.
To start an ionic 1 project check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/),
Do:

```
ionic start mynewapp blank --type ionic1
```